# When i try to download bpy shows me error

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to install `pip install bpy` in pop os linux but every time shows me this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dxhgwkzy/bpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dxhgwkzy/bpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-gazr01pj
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dxhgwkzy/bpy/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 342, in find_cookie
        codec = lookup(encoding)
    LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 394, in open
        encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 381, in detect_encoding
        encoding = find_cookie(second)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 350, in find_cookie
        raise SyntaxError(msg)
    SyntaxError: unknown encoding for '/tmp/pip-install-dxhgwkzy/bpy/setup.py': future_fstrings
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

so i need to know whats wrong
thank you

Comment: And when you throw in the relevant error message, "LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings", you end up at e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169561/pip-install-bpy-not-working-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-future-fstrings .

Comment: but when i try to run 'python3 t.py' the code has 'bpy' libariry in it gives me this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy' 
@9769953

Comment: Because it's not installed, perhaps? Did you fix your installation error?

Comment: i had install blender if that what you mean

Comment: But not the `bpy` package; that's your error in your question. It's not installed.

Comment: yes thats what i am trying to solve

Comment: See the link in my first comment.